# Ruby - code to determine the most common characterS(plural) in a string

Tags: ruby, counting, multiple-return-values

Those of you who are marking this as a duplicate - seriously, try to be more responsible. The question that you have marked as the same is quite different to the question I've asked. I've already got a great answer that was not available on any of the questions that were asked about similar topics.

My Original Question:

I see that many have asked how to find the most common letter in a string. My code for that is below. But I'd like to know how to get multiple answers to return. That is to say, if there are several letters that have the same count as most common, how do I get my method to return those only and all of them?

```
def ltr(string)
  results = string.scan(/\w/).reduce(Hash.new(0)) {|h,c| h[c] += 1; h}
  sorted = results.sort_by{|key,value| value}
  sorted[-1]
end
```

For example, if the string I input to this method is ("oh how i hate to get up in the morning")...the there are 4 each of the letters 'h', 'o', and 't'. My current method only returns the 't' with the count of '4'. How do I get the others to be returned as well?

Note: Please read questions carefully before you decide to mark them as duplicates. The question that was suggested as a possible duplicate simply shows how to count the frequencies of characters, not how to have it return only those which are the most common. Matt's answer is perfect.

Comment: Do you wanna count the characters/letters in the string?

Comment: `scan(/\w/)` seems to be the same as `chars`.

Comment: @SagarPandya: No, `scan(/./)` is the same as `chars` (only slower). `scan(/\w/)` won't pick up on spaces, or interpunction, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You had a good answer. Just keep going thru the resulting array keeping only the elements where the count is as high as the count of the first item:

```
def ltr(string)
  results = string.scan(/\w/).reduce(Hash.new(0)) {|h,c| h[c] += 1; h}
  sorted = results.sort_by{|key,value| value}.reverse
  top = sorted[0][1]
  sorted.take_while{|key,value| value == top}
end
```

Comment: thanks Matt, that's perfect. I hadn't learned about the take_while method yet. very useful!

Comment: just curious though, what's happening in that 'top' variable?  why is it necessary to put two locations "[0][1]' after 'sorted'? and how does that allow for more than 2 answers, like the 3 in our example? do they represent the key and value of each answer?